# How to access object created in one describe from a different describe?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am having some trouble currently with a project I am working on. Essentially I am trying to run multiple tests from different files together in separate describe blocks.

In the first test I would like to to set up all of the parameters and then in the second test I would like to use those parameters to fill out a form. With the way promises and describes work I am wondering if this is even possible. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I haven't tried much other than trying to make my objects global which I would prefer to stay away from and passing my objects into the second describe which doesn't work since it gets passed in before the first describe finishes and actually assigns value to them.

```js
describe('0', function () {
    let objectToPassAround = {}

    describe('1', function () {
        const test1 = require('@file1');
        test1.runTest();
    });

    describe('2', function () {
        const test2 = require('@file2');
        test2.runTest();
    });

});
```

For example, in the above, I would want to set the value of `objectToPassAround` in test1 and use that object, with it's newly set values, in test2.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all of it in a bigger describe.

```
describe('0', () => {
  let objectToPassAround = {};
  describe('1', () => {
    // you should have access to objectToPassAround
  });
  
  describe('2', () => {
    // you should have access to objectToPassAround
  });
});
```

Something to be careful is that if you're using Jasmine, the tests may run in random order and so if you set the object in test 3 and then expect for it to be set in test 4, it may not be the case. Test 4 can run before test 3. This is a feature to ensure the order of the tests do not matter since each one should be independent of each other.

Comment: The issue with this is that I would want to assign value to objectToPassAround in describe 1 and then have access to it with that value in describe 2

Comment: What is shown works, doesn't it? We have moved `objectToPassAround` in a bigger scope than the 2 describes. Are the 2 describes in different files?

Comment: My apologies, yes they are in separate files. I should've mentioned that. Updating original post.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how to do that. I was thinking of creating a third file that hold the object but every time we import the object, it will be overwritten.